# How can I resume talking to the wraith in Old Crestwood?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

So I drained the lake and started exploring the ruins of Old Crestwood, when I found an exclamation mark on my compass: A wraith wanted to talk to me, presumably with a quest of some kind!

Unfortunately, in the middle of our conversation we were interrupted by a wandering rage demon. After that bit of rudeness was dealt with, it seems my talkative wraith has buggered off. I attempted to chase it down, but it no longer seemed to want to parley. The house I found it in retains the exclamation mark on my map and compass, but there is nothing left inside to interact with.

Is there any way to restart talking with the wraith, or has this opportunity been lost forever? I've tried quick traveling around to no avail. And none of the saves (auto or otherwise) will take me back far enough without undoing hours of work.

Comment: There are actually several wraiths that all look the same that wander around the drained lake, you may be trying to interact with a different one. Try looking around for more wraiths, one might have the option to converse.

Comment: Exactly the same thing happened to me too. I couldn't resume the quest either, fortunately for me I had a save not that far off in time. But I'm afraid it's the only option until this bug (I'm positive it is) is solved